# Show that $U_n=n(n+1)(4n-1)$ given that $U_r$ is the $r$th term of the series $S_r=r^2(r+1)(r+2)$ whose sum is $S_r$

Tags: sequences-and-series

So since $U_r$ is the sum then $U_{r+1}-U_r=U_n$, then I've just set $$r=n+1,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, r=n$$
and attempted to rearrange so that $U_n=n(n+1)(4n-1)$
$$(n+1)^2((n+1)+1)((n+1)+2)-n^2(n+1)(n+2)$$
$${\Rightarrow}\,(n+1)^2(n+2)(n+3)-n^2(n+1)(n+2)$$
$${\Rightarrow}\,(n+1)\left((n+1)(n+2)(n+3)-n^2(n+2)\right)$$
$${\Rightarrow}\,(n+1)\left((n^2+3n+2)(n+3)-(n^3+2n^2)\right)$$
$${\Rightarrow}\,(n+1)(4n^2+11n+6)$$
$$(4n^2+11n+6)\,\,{\neq}\,\,n(4n-1)$$

Comment: What do you mean $r=n+1,\ r=n$?  Which of the two is true?

Comment: It seems you worked out $n+1$th term. Shouldn't you be doing $S_{n}-S_{n-1} = U_n$ instead ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @ganeshie8 in the comments, you seem to have made a small mistake in the first step of your computations.
$$U_{r+1}=S_{r+1}+S_{r}+S_{r-1}+\dots+S_2+S_1$$
$$U_{r}=S_{r}+S_{r-1}+\dots+S_2+S_1$$
$$U_{r-1}=S_{r-1}+\dots+S_2+S_1$$

Notice that $U_r-U_{r-1}=S_r$.

Whereas what you had done was $U_{r+1}-U_r=S_{r+1}$, so if you replace $n$ by $n-1$ in the answer you have obtained, you should get the correct result.